# How can I make my uibinder accept html content not just widgets as content/children

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have a uibinder call it A that I will use in another uibinders. A accepts widgets as children but not directly HTML. so my question is how to make my uibinders also accept html as content like the g:HTML or the g:HTMLPanel not just wigets?

```
NOW:
<my:A>
    <g:HTML><a href='#'>click me</a></g:HTML>
</my:A>

What I want:
<my:A>
    <a href='#'>click me</a>
</my:A>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement the [HasHTML](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasHTML.html) interface as well as the [HasSafeHtml](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/client/HasSafeHtml.html) interface in your widget.